# TFS Custom Build Template - Value Description

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have gotten a custom form and category and all that working perfectly in my build definitions. The only thing I cannot seem to figure out is how to set the description to what I want it to be.

For example, in the default template (under Build process parameters) there is a section called Automated Tests. In the description value column it says 'Run tests in assemblies matching **\ *test*.dll'.

How do I control this text for my own properties?

CLARIFICATION (example of what I am referring to):

1. Create a new build definition using the default template.
2. Go to the Process tab and add some projects (or a solution with some projects).
3. Observe that the text next to 'Items to build' is now bold and says something like 'Build 4 project(s) for 1 platform(s) and configuration(s).

The description verbiage in step 3 depends on the number of projects, platforms, etc.

This is what I am after. In my custom template I am able to get the custom dialogs working for my custom parameters BUT the description just has the full assembly name of the dialog object. I would like to customize the text there.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to open the Build process file and edit it's variables and arguments,

[image]

[image]